# Update resources through navigation properties possible?

Tags: odata, navigation-properties

I have a resource A that has a navigation property that points to resource B.  The schema looks like this:

Resource A:

- ID
- B (this is a one-to-many navigation property)

Resource B:

- ID
- Property1
- Property2

Can I update values of resource B (i.e. update property1 and property2 of B) through the navigation link of A?  In other words, can I say A.B[5].Property1 = x?

In the OData spec and examples, I only see descriptions of modifying which instance of B is associated with A (i.e. modifying /A(0)/$links/B), but not whether or not I can do a PUT/MERGE to /A(0)/B(2) and modify B itself.

Comment: Why not just send a PUT to /B(2)? ... do you need to guarantee that B(2) is related to A(0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to send a PUT request to /A(0)/B(2) and modify properties of B.

Comment: What about modifying the B collection as a whole?  Can I do a MERGE on /A(0)/B and post an array of updated property values?

Comment: Nope - for that you need the $links URLs as you noted in your question.