# How to update a set of entities?

Tags: odata, navigation-properties

Say I have resource A that contains a navigation property called "Bs" that points to a set of resource B.  Given an instance of resource A, can I batch update the set of resource B through the navigation property of resource A?

I know that I can [update a single instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092105/update-resources-through-navigation-properties-possible) of B by doing a PUT/MERGE to /A(0)/B(1).  But can I do a PUT/MERGE with an array of updated values in my request body to /A(0)/B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use batch request to perform multiple updates in one go. See http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/batch for the protocol, description. The WCF DS client library has built-in support for batch request. Other client libraries might have it as well.

Comment: I know batch requests work.  But I'm what if I don't want to use batch (the server implementation I'm using doesn't support it)?  Is it possible using the way I asked in the question?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You could do deep inserts (adding instances of B), that is I think supported, but not updating.